# Postgresql - CREATE TABLE SYNTAX ERROR USING LIKE -

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a temp table from a parent table:

This is the code that I execute with pgAdmin III (or by JDBC in Java):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_tmp LIKE table1 INCLUDING DEFAULTS;
```

And the error I received is:

```
[WARNING  ] CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_tmp LIKE table1 INCLUDING DEFAULTS
        ERROR:  syntax error at or near «LIKE»
        LÍNEA 1: CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_tmp LIKE table1 INCLUDING DEFAULTS
                                              ^
```

Reading postgresql 8.4 documentation, create tables using this, its very easy, but I don't understand where is the syntax problem.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to put the like in to parens like

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_tmp ( LIKE table1 INCLUDING DEFAULTS ) ;
```

This is not obvious from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtable.html) if you don't count parens 1:1

Answer (score 26):

I'm not a Postgresql user but the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) say that there is ( ) around the like setence.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1_tmp (LIKE table1 INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
```